# Is there a way to distinguish if a single occurence of a serial appointment is either the first, a middle or the last occurence?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

Currently all appointments, single and recurring ones are sent to a scenario where they are saved in a DB with 'dateFrom' and 'dateTo' values.

These values **must not** change if you open a single appointment of a series in Outlook which is not the first or last one.
They must only change if you explicitely click the first or last appointment and change the date or time.

**The problem:**
As soon as i edit whatever occurence the start and end date of that single occurence are saved in the DB as start and end date of the series appointment as a whole.

If there is a way to distinguish if the occurence is the starting, a middle or the ending occurrence i could do a workaround for each case.

My code that updates the values and sends it to the scenario afterwards is as follows:

```
public static IRestResponse PutMeeting(Users users, Users.User user, AppointmentItem appointmentItem, UserProperty roomName, UserProperty roomPassword, UserProperty hostPassword) {

        var client = new RestClient(users.OrchestraURL);
        var req = new RestRequest("Schedule?", Method.POST);

        req.AddOrUpdateParameter("username", user.UserName, ParameterType.QueryString);
        req.AddOrUpdateParameter("password", user.GetPasswordEncrypted(), ParameterType.QueryString);

        if (appointmentItem.IsRecurring) {
            RecurrencePattern pattern = appointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern();
            req.AddOrUpdateParameter("dateFrom", pattern.PatternStartDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + pattern.StartTime.ToString("HHmm"), ParameterType.QueryString);
            req.AddOrUpdateParameter("dateTo", pattern.PatternEndDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + pattern.EndTime.ToString("HHmm"), ParameterType.QueryString);
            req.AddOrUpdateParameter("recurringFlag", true, ParameterType.QueryString);
        }
        else {
            req.AddOrUpdateParameter("dateFrom", appointmentItem.Start.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm"), ParameterType.QueryString);
            req.AddOrUpdateParameter("dateTo", appointmentItem.End.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm"), ParameterType.QueryString);
            req.AddOrUpdateParameter("recurringFlag", false, ParameterType.QueryString);
        }
        req.AddOrUpdateParameter("spaceName", roomName.Value, ParameterType.QueryString);
        req.AddOrUpdateParameter("deleteFlag", false, ParameterType.QueryString);
        req.AddOrUpdateParameter("wishedPassword", roomPassword.Value, ParameterType.QueryString);
        if (appointmentItem.Subject == null) {
            req.AddParameter("subject", resourceDefaultLanguage.meetingSubject, ParameterType.QueryString);
        }
        else {
            req.AddParameter("subject", appointmentItem.Subject, ParameterType.QueryString);
        }

        req.AddOrUpdateParameter("hostPassword", hostPassword.Value, ParameterType.QueryString);
        req.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var response = client.Post(req);

        return response;
    }
```

"pattern.PatternStartDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + pattern.StartTime.ToString("HHmm")" had to be concated because otherwise it returns nonsense.

Comment: GetRecurrence Pattern should be what you want - and you already have it.  You would compare the two to determine if the occurrence was a start or end occurrence.  Your code looks line - but I don't see anything differentiating between a series or a meeting in your code - other than isRecurring.  Do you store both a series AND the meetings that comprise a series in the DB?

Comment: Yes isRecurring was in this case the only way to differentiate. It was literally not possible to achieve what my colleagues and myself wanted. So we handled it within a java handler in the end. Every appointment's date and time is now checked in the handler and dealt with accordingly and saved correctly in the database :)